# Mongodb queries with multiple fields

Tags: java, mongodb

I am interested to create more complex queries -- but the code I have as starting point appears to have a query helper -- if its a case of using the helper - or something more raw.

https://www.baeldung.com/queries-in-spring-data-mongodb

```
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("name").is("Eric"));
List<User> users = mongoTemplate.find(query, User.class);
```

so could you write query(where("name").is("Eric")and where("password").is("12345"))

```
@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping("/api/login2")
@ResponseBody
public Person readUser (
        @PathVariable(value="email", required=false) String email,
        @PathVariable(value="password", required=false) String password,
) {

    Person p =MongoApp.mongoOps().find(query({"email": "as@sd.com", "password": "12345"}), Person.class);

    return p;
}
```

https://www.codota.com/code/java/methods/org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query/with

so - I'm interested in learning how to do more complex queries that look for username, -- other fields -- where equals - and where or | |

Comment: chaining - like this? https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query&method=addCriteria

Answer (score 0):

Just use `and` and `or`concantinations

```
Criteria searchCriteria = Criteria
        .where("name").lte("Eric")
        .and("password").is("12345");
Query query = Query.query(searchCriteria);
User user = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, User.class);
```

Comment: what if the query is a bit dynamic - like a filter - you may not have password etc.. - wouldn't building an object then be the better approach? Or how would you use these  concantinations as a query builder?